# Webdriver - actions.draganddrop not working in w3schools page

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The `dragAndDrop` of `Actions` is not working on the [w3schools](http://httpwww.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) page:

same code works on other [page](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/)

Here is the code that i tried.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.dragAndDrop(driver.findElement(By.id("div1")), driver.findElement(By.id("div2"))).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close.. You need to find the element that has the `ondragstart` attribute. The image is what has the attribute.  Not the `<div>`

Try:

```
...
actions.dragAndDrop(driver.findElement(By.id("drag1")), driver.findElement(By.id("div2"))).build().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! But that was the first thing that i tried. It's not working ! Did that work for you ? If yes, Which OS/Browser ? I am trying on Firefox/Win8.1